# xslt with django template variables

Tags: python, xml, django, xslt, xml-parsing

Here is my [XSLT](http://pastebin.com/AQgEn3HS) file , and [xml](http://pastebin.com/xGmJg1W7)

I am processing it using python-Django as ,

```
    sheet=<pathtoxsltfile>
    style = libxml2.parseFile(sheet)
    style = libxslt.parseStylesheetDoc(style)
    result = style.applyStylesheet(xml, None)
    markup = style.saveResultToString(result)
```

Want to add value of locationID at anchor tag in xslt .

`<locationID>94</locationID>` is in [xml](http://pastebin.com/xGmJg1W7) at line no.66

And

`<a href="">see me!</a>` tag is at line 223 of [XSLT](http://pastebin.com/AQgEn3HS).

I have tried this but not working ,

```
<a href="<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="locationID"/>">see me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this ,

```
<xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="locationID "/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="locationID"/>
</xsl:element>
```

And it works.

Comment: Ah I see, it has nothing to do with django at all

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
{{ locations.0.locationID }}
```

Comment: Tried this , but not working. Can we write something like `<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="locationID "/>` ?

Comment: I assumed from your question that the xslt file was being processed first as a template by Django?  Django won't be evaluating any xslt code. I think your question is missing the information needed to answer it